# What are Yasaburo and Professor eating in episode 9?

Tags: the-eccentric-family

What are these huge donut-like things the characters are eating in the office? From the distance it looks like cylindrical donuts, but a closer look shows it's some sort of puff roll cake. I understand that the size is greatly exaggerated, but what kind of pastry is this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
(click images for full resolution)

This is from the episode 9. I remember this site had an event recently where the users were proposed to watch and then discuss this episode or something like that. I wonder if this was discussed there.

Comment: The size is not greatly exaggerated; [Japanese baumkuchen](http://www.juchheim.co.jp/english/policy/p_baumkuchen) is often rolled into the size pictured in these screenshots, though smaller versions are also widely available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me, it looks like [Baumkuchen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumkuchen), a german cake.

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the Wikipedia link, the “wood cake” is actually sold in Japan as well, and called _baumkūhen_. And they can actually be made fairly large.